# Set hostname of service container to host's hostname

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I run a docker swarm with docker swarm mode. Let's say I have 4 nodes, 1 manager, 3 worker. The hostnames are:

- manager0
- worker0
- worker1
- worker2

I start the service in `global` mode, so every node runs the service once. 
Let's say the command looks like this:

```
docker service create --name myservice --mode global --network mynetwork ubuntu wait 3600
```

`mynetwork` is an overlay network.

Now I am trying to access the hostname of the docker host in the containers, so I can pass the hostname to an application in the container.

I tried to pass the hostname with the environment variables (`--env hostname=$(hostname)`), but actually `${hostname}` is only executed on the manager and the hostname is set to `manager0` for all nodes.

Is there a way to access the hostname or pass the hostname to the containers?

Comment: The hostname of each started container is defined at startup by a random string, so I don't think we can pass it as an option on startup. Is it possible for you to run 4 separated services so you can define a different name for each one ?

Comment: That's not going to scale very well. 4 nodes is my basic setup, but in the future more nodes are added. I can't start a service for every node. Maybe I should look at a key-value store to save the hostnames or maybe get the hostnames from my DNS server.

Comment: --hostname="{{.Node.Hostname}}"
Try this. It worked for me

Answer (score 3):

You can use latest [naming templates](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/services/#create-services-using-templates) to create service with hostname.

Comment: BTW naming templates not only can be used at service creation but at service update too (not documented but tested it and really works, at least for --hostname)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the feature request, that has been implemented in docker version `17.10`

https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/30966